# passing preg_replace regex into a function

Tags: php, regex

I'm using a function to read specific query string variables and strip them of non-desired characters,

The problem is that, when I try to use the passed-in regex class of '[^ -a-zA-Z0-9]' , the function does not strip anything out... However if I hard-code that same regex into the function, it works just fine.

Any ideas?  Is there something inherently 'bad' about passing the desired regex class into a function?

Here is the function:

```
function CleanURLVariable($variablename,$defaultvalue,$allowedcharclass,$lowercase) {

    if (isset($_GET[$variablename])) {
            $temp = preg_replace('/'.$allowedcharclass.'/i','',urldecode(trim($_GET[$variablename])));

            if ($lowercase) {
                $value = strtolower($temp); 
            } else {
                $value = $temp;
            }
            return $value ;
        } else {
            return $defaultvalue;
        }
} // end of function CleanURLVariable
```

Called like this:

```
$myCleanedVariable = CleanURLVariable('kw',false,'[^ -a-zA-Z0-9]',false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is false, you need to place the hyphen at the beginning:

`[^- a-zA-Z0-9]`

Otherwise php is trying to create a range   (space) to `a`.

```
$str = "sads#$!^!#adsd#gf\$dsgf";

echo preg_replace('/[^ -a-zA-Z0-9]/i','', $str) . PHP_EOL;
echo preg_replace('/[^- a-zA-Z0-9]/i','', $str) . PHP_EOL;
```

prints:

> sads#$!^!#adsd#gf$dsgf
>
> sadsadsdgfdsgf

Comment: I think you nailed it...  I think I added the space and the dash as 'acceptable' characters at different times and didn't pay attention to the order...  When I was testing the hard-coded version, I typed in the REGEX correctly instead of copy-paste... thanks